# Identify sans-serif font, similar to Ocean Sans

Tags: font-identification

I am trying to determine which font is used, from the cover to the book [The Dawn of Everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dawn_of_Everything):

[image: The Dawn of Everything cover]

Ocean Sans seems the closest, but, for example, the angle of upper G is different.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score -1):

Try OSWALD, it's a free google font, and the bold version should suit your needs well.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to downvote. It's not very similar. The font mentioned by the OP (Ocean Sans) is closer. It's good practice to include an example of the font. Preferably showing the sentence posted by the OP so other users can evaluate the similarity.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your feedback.